# Displaying Activity Indicator in the center causes issues

Tags: reactjs, react-native, loading, activity-indicator

I know how to center the ActivityIndicator but then data is not shown, it works when I remove the style..

Here is the code:

```
  render() {
    const { loading, books } = this.props;
    const { container, loader } = styles;
    return (
      <View style={container}>
        <TopNavigation />
        {loading && <View style={loader}><ActivityIndicator color="#eaae5b" size="large" /></View>}
      </View>
    );
  }

}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  loader: { 
    position: 'absolute', 
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'}
});
```

If I remove 'loader' style it works, it shows the TopNavigation initial route..

Here are some images:

[image: With loader style]
[image: Without View which wraps loader]

Comment: what happens when you apply `style` directly to `ActivityIndicator` component?

Comment: The same thing..

Comment: can you specify some height and width to the `loader` as its positioned absolute?

Comment: Still doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

```
   <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        padding: 20,
        alignContent :'center',
        justifyContent :'center',

      }}>

      <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#45B649" />
    </View>
```

Comment: Please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55358595/edit) some explanation to your answer

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';
> const {width} = Dimensions.get('window');
>
>                       <View>
>                         style={{width:width,
>                          alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center',
>                         }}>
>                         <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="black"/>
>                       </View>
> ```

Com isso o ActivityIndicator é centralizado, se tentar usar 100% não funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Its because your view Which have style **loader** overlapping the screen, thats why your content is not showing when loading.

You can user **modal** for that

I think it can help for you

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './styles';
import {colors} from '../../utils';
import {ActivityIndicator, Modal} from 'react-native';

const Loader = ({animating, color}) => {
  return (
    <Modal visible={animating} transparent={true}>
      <ActivityIndicator
        size="large"
        animating={animating}
        color={color ? color : colors.themewhite}
        style={styles.loaderStyle}
      />
    </Modal>
   );
};
export default Loader;
```

Usage

```
<Loader animating={isLoading} />
```